# Opposite of $replaceRoot in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

Aggregation stage `$replaceRoot` can be used to move a subdocument to the root level. For instance move the `address` subdocument in here to the root:

```json
{ "name": "John Doe", "address": { "city": "Prague", "zip": "15000" } }
 ->
  { "city": "Prague", "zip": "15000" }
```

I need to do the exact opposite. That is, take the root document and move it to a subdocument. So take the root document and encapsulate it:

```json
{ "name": "John Doe", "address": { "city": "Prague", "zip": "15000" } }
 ->
  { "person": { "name": "John Doe", "address": { "city": "Prague", "zip": "15000" } } }
```

Does there exist an aggregation stage/operation with which this could be achieved? Or maybe can I hack the `$replaceRoot` itself to do this?

Comment: `$addFields` where `person: '$$ROOT'` I think

Comment: @user20042973 awesome!!! thanks  (not by itself, but in combination with `$project` it works perfectly.)
Do you want to post it as an answer (I'll accept it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "person": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
])
```

It'll also include your ObjectId, but you could add specific fields if you'd prefer